# Using the μ (mu) operator

Tags: recursion, mu-calculus

#### Problem

I've got this function:

$f(x,y)=(6-3\cdot x)\cdot(y+2)$, with $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$

Now I have to find $g=\mu f$.

#### Proposed solution

My solution was to find the smallest $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to find $f(n,y)=0$ and show that $\forall 0\leq m\leq n : f(m,y)$ is defined:

$f(0,y)=(6-0)(y+2) = 6y+12$, defined $\forall y\in\mathbb{N}$

$f(1,y)=(6-3)(y+2) = 3y+6$, defined $\forall y\in\mathbb{N}$

$f(2,y)=(6-6)(y+2) = 0$, defined $\forall y\in\mathbb{N}$

So I've found $g=\mu f=2$.

#### Questions

- Is above solution correct?
- Is it always the first parameter that becomes $n$?
- If $f(x,y)=(6-3\cdot x)\cdot(y-2)$ and $f(0,y) = (6-0)(y-2) = 6y-12$, wouldn't be $f(0,y)=0$, if $y=2$ and therefore my $n=0$ for this $y$, but for other $y$, my $n$ would be different?

Comment: Please restrain your self to one question per post; in particular, the last bullet is independent of the others. You may want to check out other questions about [tag:mu-calculus]. Regarding "real world examples", not that mu-calculus is Turing complete so every computer programis a real world example, even if they are written in a weird way.

Comment: @Raphael I moved the last bullet to a [new question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28564/20242).

If you can answer any of these questions (here or in the other thread) please don't hesitate to explain :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "$\mu$-calculus"? The [$\mu$-calculus I'm familiar with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-calculus) is an extension of modal propositional logic with least and greatest fixed-point operators but you seem to be talking about something else.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am talking about [mu recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-recursive_function). Might be that the tag is wrong. Is it? The mu operator is defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mu-Operator.html) for example.

Comment: @polym: That's how we have been using the tag. Not everyone encounters "classic" recursion theory these days, though, especially outside of Europe (?).