# Understanding the reason behind the μ (mu) operator

Tags: recursion, mu-calculus

- What is the purpose of the $\mu$ operator?
- Is there a real world example?
- Is it correct that it can create partial
  functions out of total functions and it makes a function $g$ with k
  parameters out of a function $f$ with $k+1$ parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by "the reason behind the $\mu$ operator"?

Comment: @D.W. The purpose of the μ operator. What does it accomplish.

Comment: @polym It accomplishes what its definition says it accomplishes. I also can't work out what you're asking.

Comment: [Adding the μ-operator to the five primitive recursive operators makes it possible to define all computable functions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C_operator)

Comment: @KarolisJuodel: I think this is as good an answer as this thin question can receive. Mind posting as one? [This question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/991/98) may be a useful reference, too.

Comment: Which $\mu$ operator? This letter has been used in many different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the μ-operator to the five primitive recursive operators makes it possible to define all computable functions. [It is well explained in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C_operator).